# An exercise from Revuz, Yor; equality in distribution of 2 integrals.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Here is the exercise I have been struggling to solve. It is taken from this book by Revuz and Yor: [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540643257). Here is the full text of the problem ( Exercise 3.32, chapter 4).

**Exercise (3.32)**. Let $B$ and $C$ be two independent Brownian Motions started at $0$. Prove that

$$
\int _0 ^1 (B_t + C_{1-t})^2 dt \,{\buildrel (d) \over =}\, 
\int _0 ^1 (B_t ^2 + (B_1 - B_t)^2) dt
$$

[Hint: The Laplace transform in $(\frac{\lambda ^2 }{2})$ of the right-hand side is the characteristic function in $\lambda$ of the sum of two stochastic integrals; see Exercise (2.19)]

I have been trying to apply formula 
$E \exp(\lambda M_t) = E \exp (\frac{\lambda ^2}{2} \langle M , M \rangle _t)$ for a continiouos martingale $M$, but I wasn't able to come up with a good idea what should be $M$. For example, we may write

$$
 E \exp\left(\frac{\lambda ^2 }{2} \int _0 ^1 B_t ^2  dt\right) =
E \exp\left(\frac{\lambda ^2 }{2} \int _0 ^1 (B_1-B_t) ^2  dt\right)=
  E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1 B_t dB_t\right)
$$
but it did not help me.

### Addition

Here are some 
computations. Set $W_t = C_1 - C _{1-t}$. $W$ is a BM independent on $B$, and

$$
 E \exp\left(\frac{\lambda ^2 }{2} \int _0 ^1 (B_t + C_{1-t}) ^2  dt\right) =
  E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1( B_t + C_{1-t} )dB_t\right)
$$
$$
=E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1( B_t + W_1 - W_t )dB_t\right)
=E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1 B_t dB_t+ \lambda B_1 W_1
- \lambda \int _0 ^1 W_t dB_t\right) :=F
$$

Because $W$ and $B$ are independent, we have 
$B_1W_1 = \int _0 ^1 W_t dB_t +\int _0 ^1 B_t dW_t$, so

$$
F = E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1 B_t dB_t
+ \lambda \int _0 ^1 B_t dW_t\right) = 
$$
$$
= E \exp\left(\lambda \int _0 ^1 B_t d(B_t + W_t)\right) = 
E \exp\left(\frac{\lambda ^2 }{2}2\int _0 ^1 B_t ^2 dt\right),
$$
the last equality due to relation $\langle B+M,B+M \rangle_t = 2t$. So, it should be

$$
\int _0 ^1 (B_t + C_{1-t})^2 dt \,{\buildrel (d) \over =}\, 
2\int _0 ^1 B_t ^2  dt.
$$

May it be true?

Comment: @ Sinusx: You should probably start by analysing the term $C_{1-t}$ to express it in another way. Best regards

Comment: I tried it and I "proved" that the left-hand side is actually equal in law to just $2\int _0 ^1 B_s ^2 ds$. May it be true?

Comment: Is the integrand on the right  correct? Or should the second term be $(C_1 - C_t)^2$?

Comment: Your coment on my solution was a good point. I'll think about it some more and maybe repost.